# При нажатии на ссылку открывается сразу 2 сайта - это редирект?

Tags: php, ссылки, javascript

Здравствуйте! Обмениваюсь ссылками, тут в одном обмене при нажатии на ссылку, ведущую на мой сайт, открывается сначала какой-то подозрительный игровой сайт, потом только мой. В коде я что-то ссылку на игровой сайт не нашла, хотя, я новичок в этом. Что-то закрадывается мысль, что меня пытаются обмануть, это редирект?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это JavaScript. По нажатию на ссылку наступает т.н. «событие» — это как праздник наступает, например. А как "отмечать" такой праздник — тоже подробно описывается. Вероятно, там указано «открыть <strike> шампанское </strike> игровой сайт и через 5 секунд — Ваш».

Поисковикам важно, что в коде прописано — видна ли ссылка на ваш сайт, если посмотреть исходный код страницы. Но вообще я бы с такими «партнёрами» не имел дел.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь буду знать.

Comment: Все понятно и просто объяснили)